# If I earned less than $10 in interest from my bank account, do I need to report it on my taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, interest, form-1099

I'm preparing my taxes with Turbotax, and its asking me for all the bank accounts I earned interest from. One of these accounts has earned less than $10 total for the year. Because of that this bank is not providing me with a 1099-INT form.

Since I earned less than $10 from that bank, can I skip reporting this bank to Turbotax/my tax filing? If not, how do I report the interest without the bank giving me a 1099?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you must report it. I believe the cutoff is $0.49 or less (yes, 49 cents).

[From the TurboTax site itself](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2709531-if-i-received-less-than-10-of-interest-from-my-credit-union-do-i-need-to-declare-it-it-looks-like-they-are-not-required-to-send-out-a-form-unless-it-is-over-10):

> If I received less than $10 of interest from my credit union, do I
>   need to declare it? It looks like they are not required to send out a
>   form unless it is over $10.
>
> The credit union is not required to send a form if the amount is less
>   than $10. You, however are required to report all income, no matter
>   how small, and regardless of whether you got a form or not.  The IRS
>   allows rounding, so an amount of 49 cents or less rounds to 0 and is
>   not reportable. An amount of more than 49 cents is reportable and
>   taxable. You can find the amount of interest that your credit union
>   paid on your year end statement. You can report that as if you got a
>   1099-INT (although credit unions call it a dividend, it is actually
>   interest). Just put the credit union name as the payer and put the
>   interest in Box 1.

Comment: The banks I've used didn't/don't issue a 'year-end' statement as such, but each monthly statement has interest year-to-date and YTD in December statement is the yearly total.

Comment: Here's an idea: if I have 1 million bank accounts that all earned 49 cents in interest in a year, I don't have to report them. Woohoo!

Comment: @TTT At current interest rates of 0.01% on checking accounts, you must be having $5K or less in those million bank accounts, making your net worth $5 billion or so. You sure that I in your name does not stand for Trump?

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I think I saw some MM accounts with 1% interest recently. Then I'd only need $50M in the bank. That's trump change.

Comment: This seems impossible to do correctly in practice. Like you get lunch or go on a trip or something with a group of friends and you split the bill evenly. Now whoever got paid more than their share has to calculate and report the rest to IRS?! Wow. I wonder if the fraction of the population that actually reports correctly exceeds 0.00001%...

Comment: @Mehrdad  - not sure what that scenario has to do with earning interest from a bank. Interest income is income and must be reported. Your friend paying for slightly more of a dinner bill isn't income. At minimum, it's a gift, but because you're not receiving the cash it doesn't count as a gift for tax purposes.

Comment: @BobbyScon: Not sure what you mean by "you're not receiving the cash" -- usually one person pays and others reimburse, so you would be receiving the cash. My point was that if there isn't a form sent for it and it's so small that the other types of income you have are going to dominate (such as the scenario I mentioned), then it's kind of silly to worry about it when you wouldn't worry about the bigger cases. I didn't realize there is a distinction between gift and income here though... if they have different thresholds for reporting then never mind, my bad.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Credit card rewards don't get reported as interest income either, because they only reduce the cost of what you purchased.  Same for splitting lunch -- you didn't have a net inflow, you only had your expenditure decrease.  (It's not reportable as a gift either)